# Using Tomcat JNDI + HAProxy + MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ssl, jndi, haproxy

I have a MySQL Cluster that sits behind a HAProxy

for NON-SSL,  I've configured my Tomcat JNDI Global Resource( HikariJNDIFactory)  to connect to the HAProxy. everything works...

Now I want to perform SSL-Termination/SSLOffload betwen a secure connection from Tomcat JNDI to HAProxy.

I've searched all over, all i see is pass through SSL, that requires MySQL Cluster to use SSL(which i don't want to do.).

is this possible.?

server.xml

```
...

<Resource name="jdbc/secondDataSource" 
          auth="Container"
          factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          dataSourceClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"                 
          driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://url2:3306/schema?autoReconnect=true" 
          dataSource.user="user2" 
          dataSource.password="pwd2" 
          minimumIdle="5" 
          maximumPoolSize="50" 
          connectionTimeout="300000" 
          maxLifetime="1800000" 
          connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
...
```

i have tomcat starting with SSL, however, I will not connect to HaProxy over SSL.

what would be the configuration for HaProxy to make this work.(my SQL Nodes behind the proxy are using private Ips(10.0.x.x) )